# Dynamic Link Analytical data Count for App install

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-dynamic-links

I start using firebase dynamic link for campaign in my app lately. because i can keep tracking how many click to open my app /redirecting into market.

Refer in this page https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/analytics, app installs is work only for play store. So i create some case  and end up to install my app into play store yesterday. But until now, the counter of app installs still 0.

Anyone knows how to get / how to makes work counter of App Installs in firebase dynamic link  analytical feature.